# Navigate Safari/Firefox or Chrome using the Keyboard only

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, safari

I would like to use my keyboard for as many things as possible and leave the mouse alone.

I wonder is it possible to use the keyboard only to 'click' on elements on a webpage as it is not always possible to tab between elements on a webpage.

I am using an Apple wireless keyboard on a 17" MacBook Pro 2.4GHz, running Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Gleebox](http://thegleebox.com/) extension for Firefox, Chrome and Safari is another alternative that I've just started experimenting with:

> gleeBox is an experimental project that takes a keyboard-centric approach to navigating the web. It provides alternatives to actions that are traditionally performed via the mouse. Some of these are radically more efficient than using a mouse, some not so much. In all cases, they are mostly meant for keyboard and command line lovers

I've been using it in Chrome for a short period, and so far I've liked what I've seen.

If you use all three of the above browsers regularly, then it has the additional advantage of providing the same mechanisms across all of them.

Comment: Update: Gleebox is not currently maintained on firefox and not compatible with current versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it applies but I had heard about this one.

System Preferences and go to Universal Access item in the System row.

There should be options for you to use your keyboard as a mouse as well, have a look at the options there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

In Firefox, search for the word with the link (press <kbd>CMD + F</kbd> or <kbd>/</kbd> or just start typing depending on how you've set your preferences). If the word appears more than once, <kbd>CTRL + G</kbd> to skip to next occurrence. Then, press <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Note that if a unique letter combo appears shortly before the link in question, it is sometimes easiest to type that combo then <kbd>TAB</kbd> to the link. Likewise, if the link is an image, search for a word just before the image, then <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

For example, on this page, if I just type "Woolf" and then press enter, I am brought to your user page.

Not sure about Safari and Chrome.

Comment: The `Cmd+F` trick works on Chrome too, but you need to press `Cmd+Ret` instead of `Ret`.

Answer (score 0):

In Safari 5, the [Type-To-Navigate](http://dbergey.github.com/) extension may be useful. Introduction from its homepage:

> Keep your hands on the keyboard while browsing the web. Type any text that occurs inside a link, and hit return to follow it. ⌘G jumps to the next link containing the text, and ⌘⇧G jumps to the previous. Hit ESC to cancel or exit a focused field.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite is the Vimperator ( http://www.vimperator.org/vimperator ) extension for firefox. If you're comfortable with VIM, then you'll love it.

If you're looking for something simpler, then I would recommend Gleebox, as another answer  points out.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce typing in general, consider using a macro recorder. Either the free AHK or the free iMacros for Firefox (addon).

Edit: I see you are on a Mac, so iMacros for Firefox and iMacros for Chrome is the best choice (AHK is Windows only)

Answer (score 0):

All of the suggestions given sound great.

I think the problem you will find is that Flash animations that are unfortunately the only way of navigating some (poorly designed!) sites aren't accessible using the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

See my blog post here: http://right-now-in-tech.blogspot.com/2010/08/use-google-chrome-keyboard-shortcuts-to.html

It is focussed on Chrome, but you can use those timesaving basic keyboard shortcuts on most other browsers. Safari is a bit different though, and you can look for tips and tricks on Apple's amazing support. They always have everything.