# How to use the cursor keys to navigate within web-pages in Google Chrome like Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I need an extention of plugin for chrome that act like firefox: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Accessibility#w_always-use-the-cursor-keys-to-navigate-within-webpages

Any one know how can I surf the pages in this way in chrome, like Firefox?

Comment: [Navigate Safari/Firefox or Chrome using the Keyboard only](http://superuser.com/q/179210/4377)

Comment: I need navigate the page with cursor like text editor but in this page that you introduced me, people are going to navigate in page with keyboard shortcut. I need to navigate with cursor nut keyboard shortcuts. Do you now how can I enable this feature in chrome?

Comment: Not being a FF user I simply lookd for Chrome help >> http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179     there's a link for Win, Linux, & MAC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps what you're looking for is known as `caret browsing`. In Firefox it's turned on by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>. There is an extension for Chrome that offers the same functionality: [Caret Browsing](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caret-browsing/fklpgenihifpccgiifchnihilipmbffg?hl=en)

Comment: same applies to chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus on different links & use the arrow keys to scroll up/down right out of the box in Chrome

Comment: Yes, but I need the same ability like Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still want it/didn't find it, [then take](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caret-browsing/fklpgenihifpccgiifchnihilipmbffg?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)! Nice stuff.

<sub>*Also, there is a bunch of Vim-like extensions. I've never used Vim, but after trying a bit, considering to use some. The main downside is the lack of arrow-keys navigation, tho some of them have "visual mode", but actual navigation even is this mode is mostly unusable: like, go to next symbol <kbd>L</kbd>, go back one symbol <kbd>B</kbd>. There are unused arrow keys, really..*</sub>